# undefined:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token in Laravel 5.4 and Vuejs

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

Please i'm working on a small project using laravel 5.4 and Vuejs
But lately when i tried to execute this command " npm run watch " or dev or watch-poll it gives me this problem

```
undefined:1
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch" "--" "--watch-poll"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch-poll"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch-poll"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch-poll"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kamal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-05-07T18_52_52_050Z-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch-poll"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch-poll script 'npm run watch -- --watch-poll'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run watch -- --watch-poll
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kamal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-05-07T18_52_52_381Z-debug.log

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate of [npm run dev undefined:1 issue on debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635106/npm-run-dev-undefined1-issue-on-debian/44310655)

Try deleting the `mix-manifest.json` file from `/public`

From https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/772